# Split string in Java to PHP

Tags: java, php

I have a String which goes like this in my logcat

```
24:John Smith
    Contact Number: 999999999
    Customer Address: Texas 47
    Store: Subway
    Time Frame: 4:00pm - 5:00pm
    Request: One sandwhich
    SMS ID: 2493
    Job Submitted at: 2015-03-14 18:27:45
```

And I assigned the `SMS ID` to a String variable `smsCode` with the following code:

```
smsCode = str.split("SMS ID: ")[1].split("Job Submitted at: ")[0];
```

And in my logcat it shows that `smsCode` is equals to `2493`
However when I pass the variable to PHP it doesn't work. It could be due to the spacing. I have used `smsCode.trim()` and it doesn't work as well.

It works if I put in the real value without variable:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsCode", "2493"));
```

It doesn't when its the variable as below.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsCode", smsCode));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your first example where you use the hard coded value, you are infact passing only that text value.

In the second example, using the variable `smsCode` does not actually contain the value you think it does, following the previous lines of text - `smsCode` at this point actually has a text value of `2493\n`.

Try and do as already suggested, and prepend a `\n` to your second split to remove that extra newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
smsCode = str.split("SMS ID: ")[1].split("Job Submitted at: ")[0].replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

```
smsCode = str.split("SMS ID: ")[1].split("\nJob Submitted at: ")[0];
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of what you've fixed or how this works, rather than just posting a code snippet.